# How to get array parameters from URL?

Tags: php

I have a form with 4 required inputs. They are being passed into the url if they are missing.

If all 4 is missing it'll look like:

`?required[0]=field_name&required[1]=field_email&required[2]=field_number&required[3]=field_desc`

If the first one `field_name` is missing, the array will be pushed forward one, so `field_email` will be [0]. Which means that the array is always in the 0,1,2,3 order.

What I want to find out is how can I retrieve the information so I can put a red border around the input that is missing? What I need is something like:

```
while ($i=0,$i<=3,$i++) {
    do ($requiredArray[i] == 'field_email') {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">$("#name)".css("border","1px solid #ff0000");</script>';
    } while ();
    endwhile;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to do the these validations in JS/jQuery, not on the server-side.

Comment: @alfasin Yeah totally, someone showed me jquery validation as one of the answers, I will definitely use that next time. But I really want to finish developing this as it is for now.

Comment: the way it is now it cannot work. If you want to preform the validations on the server-side, you have to build a form, submit it to the server-side which will either accept it (legit values) or display error messages next to the fields which didn't pass the validation

Comment: I posted an answer that demonstrates how to preform server-side validations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `array_search` in php as follows :

```
array_search("field_name",$_GET['required']);
```

if the value is greater than or equal to zero then you can do the processing.

Like, you can have all the values in a array variable say `$required_array` and you can use `foreach` loop like as follows:

```
foreach($required_array as $val){
 if(!(array_search($val,$_GET['required'])>=0)){
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">$("#'.$val.')".css("border","1px solid #ff0000");</script>';
 }
}
```

Comment: Interesting Could you please elaborate that for me? Because there are 4 parameter, should I use a `while` statement for this?

Answer (score 0):

Look into form validation using Jquery it will be simpler and more extensible.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: Darn! I will definitely use that next time. Unfortunately I'm stuck with working on this for this project. Thanks for that!

Comment: It offloads some processing off your server onto the client...which is always good in my book, especially for things like this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for a form that preforms the validations on the server-side:

```
<?php
$first_name = $_GET['fname'];
$last_name = $_GET['lname'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
$submit = $_GET['submit'];

if(empty($first_name) && !empty($submit)){
    $missing_fname = 1;
}
if(empty($last_name) && !empty($submit)){
    $missing_lname = 1;
}
if(empty($email) && !empty($submit)){
    $missing_email = 1;
}
?>
<table><form action="" method="get">
    <tr><td>Enter First Name:</td><td><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="<?php echo $first_name; ?>" ></td><td><?php if($missing_fname == 1) echo "<font color='red'>This field is Mandatory!</font>" ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Enter Last Name:</td><td><input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="<?php echo $last_name; ?>" ></td><td><?php if($missing_lname == 1) echo "<font color='red'>This field is Mandatory!</font>" ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Enter email:</td><td><input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"></td><td><?php if($missing_email == 1) echo "<font color='red'>This field is Mandatory!</font>" ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit"></td></tr>
    </form>
</table>
```